# Копирование памяти из структуры в массив и наоборот в C#

Tags: c#

Переписываю часть кода с c++ на c#. В с++ коде есть методы запаковки и распаковки (из массива(char) -> в структуру и наоборот). Соответственно для этого я использовал memcpy(bufer, struct, size). Удивился что в шарпах нет ничего подобного, зато есть целый зоопарк методов непонятно что делающих. Подскажите что лучше использовать в данном контексте?

Comment: по описанию похоже на бинарную сериализацию и десериализацию

Comment: Это можно сделать, использовав unsafe код (в частности, [fixed size buffers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers)) и explicit [field layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то в C# меньше возможностей "выстрелить себе в ногу" в отличии от С++. 
C# это язык более высокого уровня чем C++ или C. Поэтому прямого доступа к памяти может и не быть. Так же в C# уже нельзя так лихо переопределять типы переменных как в С++.
А так язык C# это ответ MS на Java. И работа с переменными и указателями там очень схожа и отличается от C++.